# How can I avoid an error with End Date based on Quarter End

Tags: excel, vba

I need to automatically calculate the most recent **End Date (aka QRT_END) in the format YYYYMMDD**. So since, we are in 20221120, the End Date would be the previous quarter end before today which is **20220930**.

I need to add to the below VBA syntax and not drastically change it. The previous syntax should stay as much as possible. The problem is, for any month on/before October (10th month), it works well and would display the correct previous quarter end such as 20220331, 20220630. However, when it is run in November or December, it incorrectly add a “0”, for example: when I ran today it shows 202201030. It should instead show **20220930**.

The reason the “0” exists is to account for the fact that for the first 3 Quarters, the date for example cannot be 2022331 or 2022630 or 2022930, but should display as 20220331 or 20220630 or 20220930. When it is run in January, February or March of next year, 20221231 should be displayed.

```
Private Function getQRT_END() As String 
    Dim endmonth As Variant
    Dim endyear As Variant
    Dim Day As Variant

    endmonth = Month(Date) - 1
    If endmonth = 0 Then
        endyear = Year(Date) - 1
        endmonth = 12
        day = 31
    Else
        endyear = Year(Date)
        If endmonth = 3 Then
            day = 31
        Else
            day = 30
        End if
        endmonth = “0” & endmonth
    End If
    getQRT_END = endyear & endmonth & day
End Function
```

Comment: Do you need a date or a string as result?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of...

```
endmonth = “0” & endmonth
```

Try this...

```
endmonth = Format(endmonth, "0#")
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems simpler:

```
Option Explicit
Private Function getQRT_END() As String
    Dim subtrMonths As Long
    Dim qtrEnd As Date
    
subtrMonths = (Month(Date) - 1) Mod 3
qtrEnd = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - subtrMonths, 0)

getQRT_END = Format(qtrEnd, "yyyymmdd")
End Function
```

It relies on the VBA (and Excel) behavior wherein the 0th day of any month is the last day of the previous month.

Using the `Mod` function allows us to compute how many months to subtract from the current month.